# How to add python coverage suite to Intellij?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, code-coverage, pytest-cov

I'm using basic intellij with the python plugin. I would expect this to behave pretty much like pycharm but I don't seem to be able to configure the code coverage.

Opening the menu `Show Coverage Data` it results there are no Coverage Suites configured. I assume this should come from the python plugin or from some pytest related plugin, but it's empty. How should I proceed? Am I doing something wrong? Should I install something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> basic intellij with the python plugin

Do you mean Community Edition? The thing is that Coverage feature is available in Professional Edition only. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/coverage-settings.html